# Handling big file stream (read+write bytes)

Tags: c#, byte, filestream

The following code do :

1. Read all bytes from an input file
2. Keep only part of the file in *outbytes*
3. Write the extracted bytes in outputfile

```
byte[] outbytes = File.ReadAllBytes(sourcefile).Skip(offset).Take(size).ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(outfile, outbytes);
```

But there is a limitation of ~2GB data for each step.

**Edit:** The extracted `byte`s size can also be **greater than** `2GB`.

**How could I handle big file ?** What is the best way to proceed with good performances, regardless of size ?

Thx !

Comment: Why read all bytes if you're going to skip? Why not just open the file as a stream, seek to where you want and read. Reading 2gb just to get 2 bytes, 3 bytes in, is incredibly wasteful. LINQ is a hammer; not every problem is a nail. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Use the [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netcore-3.1) class to open a stream for a file. From there you can skip ([`Seek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek?view=netcore-3.1)) to an offset and [`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=netcore-3.1) a chunk of arbitrary size (async or synchronous) and write it to your output file

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't want to get only 2 bytes, I need more than 2GB

Comment: @Veiz You missed Caius Jard's point. You're reading 2 GB into _memory_ in order to get a small(er) amount and write it back out to a file.

Comment: "smaller amount" can be greater than 2GB

Comment: OK, let's start from the beginning: why are you reading so much data into memory? Forget your goals, concentrate on your implementation. Why are you reading so much into memory?

Comment: Well i don't know if there is another way. I need to extract big part of big file.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: It doesn't matter that *"smaller amount" can be greater than 2GB* because if it was 3 gb you can read 1 megabyte and write it 3000 times - you never used more than a megabyte of memory and you wrote 3000 mb to disk. The original point I was making is that if you read a whole multi gigabyte file into memory and then use linq to `Skip(3).Take(2)` to get the two bytes, 3 bytes in you've made a massive waste of resources..plus objects cannot be larger than 2gb in .net anyway.. Don't read the whole file, repeatedly read and fill a buffer and write and reuse the buffer

Comment: @DmitryBychenko ty this allow to handle big objects but byte array are still limited to 2^32 elements. And i don"t want to load all in memory if possible.

Comment: @CaiusJard i understand. There is a native way to do it in .NET or do i need a custom function?

Comment: FileStream as I linked allow you to treat massive file like small byte array; you open stream, you seek to where you want, you read into a buffer, you write your buffer to another file, read again etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to stream the data from one file to the other, only loading small parts of it into memory:

```
public static void CopyFileSection(string inFile, string outFile, long startPosition, long size)
{
    // Open the files as streams
    using (var inStream = File.OpenRead(inFile))
    using (var outStream = File.OpenWrite(outFile))
    {
        // seek to the start position
        inStream.Seek(startPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Create a variable to track how much more to copy
        // and a buffer to temporarily store a section of the file
        long remaining = size;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[81920];

        do
        {
            // Read the smaller of 81920 or remaining and break out of the loop if we've already reached the end of the file
            int bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.Min(buffer.Length, remaining));
            if (bytesRead == 0) { break; }

            // Write the buffered bytes to the output file
            outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            remaining -= bytesRead;
        }
        while (remaining > 0);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
CopyFileSection(sourcefile, outfile, offset, size);
```

This should have equivalent functionality to your current method without the overhead of reading the entire file, regardless of its size, into memory.

Note: If you're doing this in code that uses async/await, you should change `CopyFileSection` to be `public static async Task CopyFileSection` and change `inStream.Read` and `outStream.Write` to `await inStream.ReadAsync` and `await outStream.WriteAsync` respectively.

Comment: Well it looks like that's exactly what I need. Learned something new. Ty sir.

Comment: @Veiz Sorry! I forgot to add the line to subtract the bytes read from the remaining. I've edited it now.

Comment: Can i ask why you choose 81920 size for byte array?

Comment: @Veiz Because it's the default buffer size used by Microsoft's [CopyTo](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs#L53) method in `Stream`.

Answer (score 2):

Example to FileStream to take the middle 3 Gb out of a 5 Gb file:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte{1024*1024];
using(var readFS = File.Open(pathToBigFile))
using(var writeFS = File.OpenWrite(pathToNewFile))
{

  readFS.Seek(1024*1024*1024); //seek to 1gb in

  for(int i=0; i < 3000; i++){ //3000 times of one megabyte = 3gb 
    int bytesRead = readFS.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    writeFS.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }

}
```

It's not a production grade code; Read might not read a full megabyte so you'd end up with less than 3Gb - it's more to demonstrate the concept of using two filestreams and reading repeatedly from one and writing repeatedly to the other. I'm sure you can modify it so that it copies an exact number of bytes by keeping track of the total of all the bytesRead in the loop and stopping reading when you have read enough

Comment: Ty for the POC.